# Make a space character in Inkscape SVG font editor?

Tags: fonts, svg, inkscape

When using Inkscape to make SVG fonts, I'm just curious if there's a way to make blank characters - characters that are just space. Inkscape requires that you press [get curves from selection] for a character to not be replaced by the missing char symbol, but spacing characters don't have curves.

My current workaround is to just make a wide but invisibly thin path and use that as the character, but that is, after all, a workaround.

What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that and then use the XML viewer in inkscape to remove the `d` attribute (the glyph path) from the <glyph> element that corresponds to space.